# Proof check: The cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be the cone in $\mathbb R^3$:
$$X=\big\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:z^2=x^2+y^2\big\}.$$
I claim that $X$ is a smooth 2-dimensional manifold. Let's prove it:

I follow the [Nigel Hitchin's](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/files/LectureNotes/Differentiable_manifolds/manifolds2014.pdf) definition of smooth manifold. First of all, consider:
$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
\varphi_1&:U_1=\{(x,y,z)\in X:z\geq 0\}&\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2\\
&(x,y,z)&\longmapsto (x,y)
\end{array}\quad\text{and}\quad \begin{array}{rcll}
\varphi_2&:U_2=\{(x,y,z)\in X:z< 0\}&\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2\\
&(x,y,z)&\longmapsto (x,y)
\end{array}$$
It is pretty clear that $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are bijection onto its images and $\varphi_1(U_1)=\mathbb R$, $\varphi_2(\mathbb R^2)=\mathbb R^2-\{0\}$ are open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$. Thus $(U_1,\varphi_1)$ and $(U_2,\varphi_2)$ are local charts on the set $X$.

Morever, $U_1,U_2$ covers $X$ and $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$. This implies that $\mathcal A=\{(U_1,\varphi_1), (U_2,\varphi_2)\}$ is an atlas over $X$ and $X$ is a smooth manifold.

Is my reasoning correct? Many thanks!

Comment: $U_1$ is not an open subset of the cone.

Comment: Hint: the cone is not a manifold, although $X\setminus\{0,0,0\}$ is.

Comment: @ArcticChar I am not considering any topology on $X$ (I am folloging the N. Hitching definition of manifold)

Comment: Well, then your $X$ has a bijection to $\mathbb R^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: I'd strongly suspect Hitchin just forgot to put the word "open" there.

Comment: @Thorgott No I think it's deliberate. He says this on page 9: "Many books give a slightly different definition – they start with a topological space, and insist that the coordinate charts are homeomorphisms. This is fine if you see the world as a hierarchy of more and more sophisticated structures but it suggests that
in order to prove something is a manifold you first have to define a topology. As we’ll see now, the atlas does that for us."

Comment: Ah OK, I now understand what he does. He takes the charts on an abstract space and then equips it with the topology induced by this charts to make it into a manifold in the usual sense. This is fair game. The issue with OPs example, in this context, is that the topology induced by these charts on the cone is not the same as the subspace topology on the cone as subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.